# How to train in taekwondo at 77 years old

Tags: tae-kwon-do

How do I progress in the harmony program with arthritis in both hips, lower spine, and right ankle. I am 77 years of age and young.

Comment: This question makes no sense whatsoever. Could you please clarify what your problem is?

Comment: In order to progress, it helps to understand where the starting point is.

Comment: First of all, hats off for taking this decision at that age.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to discuss it with your instructor (if you already have one) or find an instructor who will make adjustments to support you.

It is also important not to compare yourself to younger students in the class; everyone is different and has different limitations on what they can or can't do.

At the taekwondo school I train (and assist) at, we have a student who started training after he retired; he is a similar age to you and now a black stripe (1st Kup). My instructor and I understand that he has limitations and we do our utmost to support him.

Ultimately, you know what you can and can't do; your instructor should encourage you to try, but without hurting yourself.

Comment: I would like to contact this man you talk of and perhaps get some info from him is that possible

Comment: Many thanks for your interest I am from the Edinburgh area is that near yourself

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't start up a martial art.  However, recognize that most instructors aren't also 77 years old.  That means, they don't know what you know.  They don't understand body physiology at that age.  So you could end up with an instructor who could hurt you - badly.  Your muscles aren't as flexible as they used to be, the ticker is usually weaker, your breathing is more difficult, your muscles don't recover as quickly, and you need more time to warm up.

An instructor who doesn't see this will have you doing 10 minute sparring sessions, or trying to do a split, or spar with a younger kid... and that can be a recipe for disaster if s/he doesn't know how to watch out for your safety.

So you need to work with the instructor, and tell him or her what you are capable of doing.  Of course, the instructor's job is to get you to do things you can't do, so there has to be some give and take, and patience.

You should work with your doctor, as well.  At home, you should spend a good deal of time working the muscles - particularly dynamic stretching.  Several times a day, you should look for opportunities to do these kinds of exercises.  They need not be a workout in of themselves, you can take 5 minutes here and there and work on the hips, back, and neck.  This is generally good for overall fitness anyway - and that's the point: stay active all the time.